# Isothermal process of free expansion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

**The problem that arose my confusion:**

> One mole of a monatomic ideal gas undergoes a cyclic process as shown in the figure
> (where $V$ is the volume and $T$ is the temperature). Which of the statements below is (are) true?

[image]

> (A) Process I is an isochoric process
>
> (B) In process II, gas absorbs heat
>
> (C) In process IV, gas releases heat
>
> (D) Processes I and III are not isobaric

---

The correct options are

> (B) (C) (D),

and I understand

> how (A) is false.

**My confusion:**
I was having issues when dealing with the thermodynamical process that the gas undergoes during process II. It seems that statement (B) need not necessarily be true since II can be a **free expansion process**. If II allows for heat to flow in and out of the system (so now it is an **Isothermal expansion**), then (B) is a true statement. How does one resolve such a conflict?

Comment: Since the temperature is shown varying with volume at every point through the process, the process must be reversible.  Otherwise, the temperature would not be well-defined through the process, since the system would not be close to equilibrium.  Free expansion is an irreversible process, so this diagram would not correspond to that.

Comment: Thanks, this is what was confusing me. Before, I wasn't able to to convince myself that this is a reversible process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since it is an ideal gas, the internal energy is a function only of the temperature T. Since process $II$ is isothermal, there is no net change in internal energy and thus:

$$\Delta U = \Delta W + \Delta Q = 0$$

With this sign convention, $Q$ is the heat supplied *to* the system and the work done by the system to the surroundings is $dW = -pdV$.

Implying $\Delta W = - \Delta Q$. Now, use the ideal gas law $PV = nRT$ to compute work:

$$\Delta W = \int_{II} dW = \int_{II} -pdV = \int_{V_{II}}^{V_{III}} -\frac{nRT}{V}dV = -nRT \ln(\frac{V_{III}}{V_{II}}) $$

Now, since 
$$\Delta Q = -\Delta W = nRT\ln(\frac{V_{III}}{V_{II}})$$

and $V_{III}$ is greater than $V_{II}$, $\Delta Q > 0$, meaning that the system absorbs heat, as stated in option (B)

Comment: Well, can't the process be adiabatic and isothermal as well (since it hasn't been mentioned in the problem)? So then the process II becomes a free expansion doesn't it?